# Auto Refresh a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to auto refresh a specific div, i tried the following code but it make a lot of requests to the server instead of one every 5 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            refresh();
        });

        function refresh() {
            $.get('site', function(result) {
                $('#div').html(result);
            });
            setTimeout('refresh()', 5000);
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Using a string is valid, and does work, so that's probably not the issue, even it shouldn't be done because it evals the string internally.

Comment: You should use setInterval instead of timeout and outside of the refresh function itself because it drops in an infinite loop of running function

Comment: FYI, the timeout should be inside the callback, otherwise the recursive function doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Generally when you use a recursive function with an ajax call, that's what you want, to call the timeout when the ajax call has completed, so as to get consistent times even when factoring in the time the ajax call takes, and that's why you generally shouldn't use intervals with ajax. To not stop at a failure, one simply places the timeout in the `always` callback instead.

Comment: @adeneo, I see now what you mean thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to call the function every 5 sec, use `setInterval` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var interval = setInterval(refresh, 5000);
});

function refresh() {
    $.get('site', function (result) {
        $('#div').html(result);
    });    
}
```

Also, use `clearInterval(interval)` to clear out the Interval.

Note : Any interval/timeout/recursive function with such case will fire regardless of whether the `.get()` request has returned.